# Downloaded PDF is corrupted, how can I download it correctly using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, https, python-requests

I am trying to download pdf using requests(python 2.7), and, this is the code that I am using:

```
file_resp = requests.post(file_url, data=payload, headers={"Referer":file_referer_url})
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file_resp.content)
```

But, downloaded pdf is corrupted. This is the **response header** that I got:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 05:49:32 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Also, response is something like this:
JVBERi0xLjQNCiW0tba3DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8P...(long sequence like this...)

Please, can anyone help me with what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I can see that Content-Type is "text/html;", instead of pdf... I am not sure, may be this is why it is causing an issue while downloading. Any suggestions on how should I handle this?

Comment: Though no one helped me with this small task, here is the link, if someone might come across similar situation, solve it by referring this.
https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is of type string, so simply Base64 decode the data with base64.b64decode and write it to a file.

```
with open('application.pdf', 'wb') as file_to_save:
    decoded_pdf_data = base64.b64decode(file_resp.content)
    file_to_save.write(decoded_pdf_data)
```